# scientific notation in objective c (confused with base e calculation)

Tags: objective-c, ios, math

It has been a while since I did any base e calculations. I can't seem to remember how to do this: -5e-6

In my code, I have `double x = -5*M_E-6`, which equals `(-5*M_E) - 6`, which roughly equals -19.6. This, however, does not equal -5e-6.

How do I represent -5e-6 programmically?

Thanks.

Comment: -5 * (M_E ^ -6) if it's a calculation.  But this could be scientific notation.

Comment: @RoboticCat: `^` is xor, not power.

Comment: You should update your question since you didn't actually want anything related to base e, but actually wanted scientific notation.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the reminder ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not base e math, that's [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). Type it as it is shown.

> Note that in this usage the character *e* is not related to the mathematical constant *e* or the exponential function *e<sup>x</sup>*...

Comment: ahh crap you may be right. Let me go look up what scientific notation is @@

Comment: Thank you, it is scientific notation ^_^

Answer (score 3):

If you want `-5 x 10-6`, you use `-5e-6`. That's not the same as using the mathematical constant `e` (2.71828-ish) in a calculation, which is what happens with `M_E`.